# MySQL: How to select distinct values from a table?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have huge table with many rows and columns, but I will describe only important of them:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| artikel   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | IDX | NULL    |                |
| color     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example data:

```
 1    apple        1000      red
 2    apple        1000      yellow
 3    lemon        2000      blue
 4    lem on       2000      green
 5    lemon        2000      black
 6    apple        1000      white
 7    cherry       3000      lime
 8    cherry       3000      pink
 9    lemon        2000      silver
10    apple        1000      gold
```

As you can see, the index is on `artikel`, each `artikel` has some `name` (for each `artikel` there is the same `name`) and different `color`. Everything is OK, but with row `4` there is problem, there is wrong `name` = `lem on`, it should be `lemon`.

I want to select these rows (`GROUP BY artikel`), where there is not unique `name`, but `HAVING COUNT(name) > 1`. So my select will return one row, where will be `artikel` = `2000`.

I tried `HAVING`, `DISTINCT`, but with no success.

How can be done that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select artikel
from exampledata
group by artikel
having min(name) <> max(name);
```

You can also use `count(distinct)` in the `having` clause.  But `count(distinct)` typically requires more work than just comparing the minimum and maximum values.